# Html with jquery function find

Tags: jquery

I have my HTML page:

```js
function Aggiorna(number){
  
  var myVar = $("#number").find('input[name=DTMMAA]').val();
  alert('Importo: '+myVar);
}
```

```html
<?php $number = 0; ?>
<tr id='<?php echo $number++; ?>'>
  <td><input type="text" style="width: 70px; text-align: right" name="IMLORD" id="IMLORD" class="decimal-2-places" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder=",00" maxlength="6"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" style="width: 70px;" name="DTMMAA" id="DTMMAA" class="dtmmaa" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="MM/AAAA" maxlength="6"></td>
                                    
                                     
<td><div align="left"><button type="button" value="Aggiorna" onclick="Aggiorna('<?php echo $number; ?>')" 
                                                class="btn btn-primary" style="float: left;" aria-label="Left Align">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" style="color:yellow" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registra
                                                </button></div>
                                    </td>
```

I have more records in my table and I would like to raise the value of IMLORD and DTMMAA when I use the button (Aggiorna), but my javascript don't work `(alert('Importo: '+myVar);)` . Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: Why look for `input[name=DTMMAA]` when the id is `DTMMAA` too, just use `$('#DTMMAA')` unless you have more than one element with the same id and then it's invalid HTML

Comment: Your code snippet is failing with error: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 26,
  "colno": 27
}

Comment: Lot of errors in your code. I would suggest you to check your console window for jquery errors also your `input` tag has a missing closing `/`

Answer (score 0):

i modify you code a bit and i think now its work 
be sure to have table and close TR 
its better to have letter before number in the id of element 
eg.

```
<?php $number = 0; ?>
<tr id='a<?php echo $number++; ?>'>

onclick="Aggiorna('a<?php echo $number; ?>')
```

working demo

```
function Aggiorna(number){
  var mytr = $("#"+number).find("input.dtmmaa").val();
    console.log(number);

  console.log(mytr);
   alert('Importo: '+mytr);
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr id='a0'>
  <td>
    <input type="text" style="width: 70px; text-align: right" name="IMLORD" id="IMLORD" class="decimal-2-places" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder=",00" maxlength="6">
  </td>
                                    <td>
                                      <input type="text" style="width: 70px;" name="DTMMAA" id="DTMMAA" class="dtmmaa" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="MM/AAAA" maxlength="6">
  </td>


<td>
  <div align="left"><button type="button" value="Aggiorna" onclick="Aggiorna('a0')" 
                                                class="btn btn-primary" style="float: left;" aria-label="Left Align">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" style="color:yellow" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registra
                                                </button></div>
  </td>     </tr>
</table>
```

working on codepen.io

http://codepen.io/Joxo/pen/XNjPEM

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `<table>` tag before `<tr>`, that's probably why the id is not found

```js
function Aggiorna(number) {

  var myVar = $("#number").find('input[name=DTMMAA]').val();
  alert('Importo: ' + myVar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php $number=0 ; ?>
<table>
  <tr id='number'>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 70px; text-align: right" name="IMLORD" id="IMLORD" class="decimal-2-places" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder=",00" maxlength="6">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 70px;" name="DTMMAA" id="DTMMAA" class="dtmmaa" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="MM/AAAA" maxlength="6">
    </td>


    <td>
      <div align="left">
        <button type="button" value="Aggiorna" onclick="Aggiorna('<?php echo $number; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: left;" aria-label="Left Align">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" style="color:yellow" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registra
        </button>
      </div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are not using your `number` argument inside your `Aggiorna` function.
You are just selecting an element with the literal id `number` (`#number` is selecting an element with `id="number"`). You probably meant `$("#"+number)`.

Since you are numbering the row ids, I assume that you have multiple rows and the button needs the value from the same row.

You can remove all the row number handling, if you just use the [`.closest(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the row of the button and then just find your `'input[name=DTMMAA]'` inside that row.

You can also remove the JavaScript function call from the HTML, if you bind your handler with the [`.on(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

I added a `row` class to your table rows and `aggiorna` class to your buttons. I also removed your ids, because multiple same ids are invalid HTML. You will have to use classes if you want to reference them in CSS.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".aggiorna", function(e) {
    var myVar = $(this).closest(".row").find('input[name=DTMMAA]').val();
    console.log('Importo: '+myVar);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 70px; text-align: right" name="IMLORD" class="decimal-2-places" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder=",00" maxlength="6"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 70px;" name="DTMMAA" class="dtmmaa" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="MM/AAAA" maxlength="6"></td>
        <td>
            <div align="left">
                <button type="button" value="Aggiorna" class="btn btn-primary aggiorna" style="float: left;" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" style="color:yellow" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registra
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>                                                                 
    <tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 70px; text-align: right" name="IMLORD" class="decimal-2-places" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder=",00" maxlength="6"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 70px;" name="DTMMAA" class="dtmmaa" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="MM/AAAA" maxlength="6"></td>
        <td>
            <div align="left">
                <button type="button" value="Aggiorna" class="btn btn-primary aggiorna" style="float: left;" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" style="color:yellow" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registra
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>                                                                 
    <tr>
</table>
```

If you are binding the handler after the page is loaded, you can just use

```
$(".aggiorna").on("click", function(e) {
```